# Storing field from drop down into table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to store information from a group of drop down menus into a table that I can store and display as well. I was wondering how I would put this into a new table. I generated a new table but I'm not sure how I would store it. I am getting a POST error when I click on the button. Here is my show.html.erb file with the drop down menus:

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <%= form_for(Stc.new, url:{action:'new'}) do |f| %>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= label_tag course.title, course.title %>
  <%= f.label :semester %>
  <%= select_tag(:semester, options_for_select([['--------','-----------'], ['Fall', 'Fall'], ['Spring', 'Spring']])) %>
  <%= select_tag(:semester, options_for_select([['--------','-----------'], ['2012', '2012'], ['2013', '2013'], ['2014', '2014'], ['2015', '2015'], ['2016', '2016'], ['2017', '2017']])) %>
  <%end%>

   <%= f.submit "Student taken course", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here is my table in stc.rb:

```
  class Stc < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :course
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

Comment: please indent your code properly

Comment: not sure why are you using two select_tag for same field?

Comment: what are the column name in `Stc` model, could you see in schem.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action should be `create`.Normally you don't need to specify action: `create`, rails will know this if you render from a `new` action. But I'm not sure how you're going to handle the code in the controller. You can read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).
The code can be like this:

```
<%= form_for(Stc.new, url:{ action: 'create' }) do |f| %>
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= label_tag course.title, course.title %>
    <%= f.label :semester %>
    <%= select_tag(:semester, options_for_select([['--------','-----------'], ['Fall', 'Fall'], ['Spring', 'Spring']])) %>
    <%= select_tag(:semester, options_for_select([['--------','-----------'], ['2012', '2012'], ['2013', '2013'], ['2014', '2014'], ['2015', '2015'], ['2016', '2016'], ['2017', '2017']])) %>
  <%end%>

  <%= f.submit "Student taken course", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```